# При внесении изменений в базу данных с использованием всех созданных форм сначала вводятся данные в подчинённую или главную таблицу?

Tags: ms-access

Пытался искать ответ на этот вопрос в документации Microsoft и на других сторонних площадках, но так ничего внятного не нашел. Буду очень рад, если предложите возможное решение!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access имеет средства контроля целостности данных. В частности, связь между главной и подчиненной таблицей требует, чтобы каждой записи в подчиненной таблице соответствовала запись в главной таблице.

Средства контроля целостности не позволят ввести записи в подчиненную таблицу, не имеющие связанной с ней записи в главной таблице. Поэтому при вводе последовательность действий должна быть такой: сначала ввести данные в главную таблицу, потом в подчиненную.

Подробнее о контроле целостности в MS Access можете прочитать в учебнике Н.В. Макаровой "Информатика и ИКТ. Учебник для 11 класса. Базовый уровень".

[image: Учебник "Информатика и ИКТ, 2009, стр. 161"]